# configure so that no records can be the same

Tags: mysql

I remember in my work in past projects I have ran across a MySQL error message that stated that no records can be the same ( all columns ) because then they cannot be individually selected. Unfortunately my MySQL doesn't give me this error and I have a problem.

I have a table to store a user's favorite topics ( or articles if you will ) which is fairly simple

```
CREATE TABLE `ad_favorites` (  
    `ad_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
    `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
    KEY `ad_id` (`ad_id`),  
    KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),  
    CONSTRAINT `ad_favorites_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ad_id`) REFERENCES `ad` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,  
    CONSTRAINT `ad_favorites_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I need to not be able to insert two same records and get an error in case there is such an attempt so that in my php my `affected_rows` property will show 0.

Long story short if I have a record and I try to insert it again I must get a MySQL error, is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make the two columns a composite primary key,

```
PRIMARY KEY (ad_id, user_id)
```